# Left invariant vector field from action

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds

I'm trying to calculate the left invariant vector fields on $\mathbb{R}^2$ from the action $\mu: G \times \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ with the multiplication $$\mu((a,b,c), (x,y)) = (ax-cy, by). $$ I know the identity element on $e\in G$ is $e = (1,1,0)$, and I've calculated

$$ \begin{align*} \mu_{g\ast}^1(\partial_x) &= \partial_x(\mu_g^1) = a, \\
\mu_{g\ast}^2(\partial_x) &= \partial_x(\mu_g^2) = 0,\\ 
\mu_{g\ast}^1(\partial_y) &= \partial_y(\mu_g^1) = -c, \\
\mu_{g\ast}^2(\partial_y) &= \partial_y(\mu_g^2) = b,
\end{align*} $$ giving $X_1= a\partial_x$ and $X_2 = b\partial_y - c\partial_x$ as the left invariant vector fields, but now I'm not sure how to write $a,b,c$ in terms of $x$ and $y$. Am I missing something?

Comment: What do you mean by left-invariant vector fields?  If you mean the vector fields on $\mathbb R^2$ that are invariant under pushforward by $\mu_g$ for all $g \in G$, then I think the zero field is the only example - for any pair of points in $x,y \in \mathbb R^2$ there will be many different group elements sending $x$ to $y$, which will have different differentials.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis I ultimately want to calculate the infinitesimal generators, flows, and one-parameter subgroups for this action. It's my understanding that in order to do this, I need to first calculate the left invariant vector fields on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: But what is your definition of this last term? I'm not sure what source you're reading, but I think you might mean to calculate the left-invariant fields on the group $G = \{ \left[\begin{matrix}a & -c \\ 0 & b\end{matrix}\right] : a,b \ne 0 \}$ instead.

Comment: I believe it's the vectors $X\in T_e\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $\mu_{g\ast}(X_e) = X_g$, but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: How would what I did differ from calculating the left-invariant vector fields on the group that you suggested?